# Multiprocessing datasets Python - Automatically generates batches

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

I am using the module multiprocessing of Python for processing +30 datasets with 2 heavy concatenated functions.

The first function *func1* stores a partial result in a directory that the second function *func2* is calling after. The second function returns nothing, just generates another file with outputs stored.

This is a lineal process like the following:

```
def my_multiprocessing(input_path):

    out_path = func1(input_path)

    #Func2 uses out_path as input. Func2 returns no Python variable, just a file.
    func2(out_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_pool = Pool(cpu_count())  
    my_pool.map(my_multiprocessing, list_of_30_datasets_path)
```

Now, I expect multiprocessing to work lineally; for each dataset, solve first *func1* and after use **out_path** variable to solve *func2*.

But so far, it is working by batches, solving ALL *func1* for the 30 datasets first.
How can it process after the *func2* if there will have NO **out_path**s? (Python overwrites)
Is there some cool magic behind I am far to understand?

Please help me, it is my first multiprocessing task and I expect it to work for a week, can't mess it up.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, the issue is that each input file to `func1` will generate an output file with the same name, and the different datasets will overwrite eachother? Or have I missunderstood the problem?

Comment: func1 will generate out_path with unique basenames each. But the point is that I am processing by steps, not lineally, first I process all datasets with func1 and once it finish, with func2.
My concern is how multiprocessing manages this, where it stores the different out_path

Comment: Do you have to first process all datasets with `func1`? They way yout code is written does not guarantee that. It only ensures that for each dataset, `func1` is called before `func2`.